# CSS3: Top align of list item

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

**CSS3: Top align of list item.**

See image as below. How can I align a blue arrow to align on top of a senetence of each list. I'm using jQuery 1.7 and it is for iOS (iPhone).

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/align.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/align.png)

```
ul.lists{ padding:0 0 15px 0;}
ul.lists li{ line-height:18px; border-bottom:1px #bfeaf0 solid; padding:6px 12px;       
background:url(../images/arrow_cyan.svg) no-repeat left; } /* no-repeat left top; */
```

I've tried to include a js as offset
   $("li:last").offset({ top: -15 }); 
but it did not work properly because I don't know how to move all blue arrows to align each list even the sentence might run into more than one line.

UPDATE:
I've tried this...

[Top align http://www.kerrydeaf.com/align2.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/align2.png)

```
background:url(../images/arrow_cyan.svg) no-repeat left top;
```

LAST UPDATE:
It is now solved.
    background:url(../images/arrow_cyan.svg) no-repeat left 10px;

[Top align http://www.kerrydeaf.com/align3.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/align3.png)

Comment: Try to change your third css line to: `background:url(../images/arrow_cyan.svg) no-repeat top left; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS, Luke

```
ul.lists li {
  background:url(../images/arrow_cyan.svg) no-repeat left top; 
}
```

Comment: Replace `top` parameter with exact pixel offset you need (5px or 6px or more/less). Some tries and everything will look as good as you need.

Comment: Do you mean add more white on graphics to acheive it or add 5ppx or 6px instead of 'top'?

Comment: Got it...background:url(../images/arrow_cyan.svg) no-repeat left 10px; Thank you Kugaevsky.

Comment: No graphic changes. Just pure CSS. I think something like 9px should be well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with

```
background-position:left top;
```

David,

Answer (score 0):

Using background-position with a possibly negative vertical value should work. The exact value you'll have to determine by trial and error.